# PHP - convert ASCII to Unicode in a mixed string

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

I have a string with Unicode and ASCII characters.

I can use `utf8_decode` to convert ASCII to Unicode characters, but it also converts unicode to unicode characters. How can I filter or convert only ASCII characters to Unicode in a mixed string?

For example:

```
utf8_decode(& #225; rỉ);
~> á rỉ
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things. ASCII characters are 7-bit, 0x00 to 0x7F. So if you have a Unicode string, the ASCII characters don't need to be converted, because they are the same in Unicode...

Now, your á is 0xE1, thus it's not ASCII but `ISO Latin 1`. And you can't have two encodings in one string (or you're up shit creek....). So what you need is to convert from ISO Latin 1 to UTF-8.

Comment: how to convert from ISO Latin 1 to UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

á is not an ASCII character. [ASCII charset table](http://www.robelle.com/library/smugbook/ascii.html)

You can also try this.

```
echo mb_convert_encoding('&#225; rỉ', "UTF-8", "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `$string = iconv('ASCII//TRANSLIT','UTF-8', $string);`